# Is there a way to prompt a user to turn on/off WiFi in iOS from an Alert?

Tags: ios, wifi

I have this problem where when I go out my iPhone 6s on iOS 9.3.4 tries to connect to every hotspot I pass. Then when it is trying to connect I can't get emails/texts/alerts etc. My solution has been to turn off WiFi. But then I get home again and forget to turn it back on and I wonder why my internet is so slow until I remember to turn WiFi back on. I got the idea for an app to build a geofence around my house and turn off WiFi when I leave that area. I know I can't do this automatically because of the iOS sandboxing restriction, but can I pop an alert when I cross the geofence boarder that asks if I want to turn WiFi on/off?

I haven't found anything current that allows me to do this. I have searched extensively and only found "Stumbler" but it appears to be from 2007. I only know C# and do all my app development in Xamarin so C# code would be best or if you know of any libraries/components/plugins.

Also, I just want this app for myself so no need to submit to app store.

Comment: Well you can surely do that. YOu just need to calculate your current location and increase the accuracy for the location manager which will update you the location change details for every x metres.You can then navigate user to settings app to turn on/off the wifi,

Comment: I think iPhone will not automatically connect to unknown network. For those networks that you don't want your phone to connect automatically, you can click the "i" button on the right of the row and in the detail page, click "Forget This Network" to forget it.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I "Forget" networks and it still finds others. I tried to enable "Ask to join unknown networks" and that is worse because every time my phone requests data a box pops up showing available networks.

I'm not worried about the geofencing part I just can't figure out how to pop an alert that says, "Disable WiFi?"  "Yes" "No" or even navigate to the WiFi Switch in Settings.